# What's the easiest way to implement a timer in Java?

Tags: java, jsf, time

I'm building a JSF application ( assignment for college ) where people log in the site, bid and when the time expires a pop up window or an output tag announces who is the winner.

So I want to know how can I make an output tag update his value every second ( to show the user how much time he has to bid ) and when it reaches 60 seconds it calls a method to show the pop up window ( or tag ) and announce the winner.

Thanks.
Obs: ESL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Richfaces has got [`a4j:poll`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/poll.jsf) , which fits for you

Comment: Isn't using an extra library for what is basically a javascript timer and a simple Thread.sleep() (obviously we can do that much more efficient, but for a simple homework it should work fine) a bit overkill?

Comment: You need to maintain communications with the server, retrieve the status of bids etc, so comet is exactly what you need. Also, you can't track the timer only on the client.

Comment: Also, using JSF components, even when they are from an extra library is not an overkill, since that's exactly what JSF is for (reusable components and templates).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a [TimerTask](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) is what you want.